# Relating convergence in probability to almost sure convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I don't know whether I'm gettin totally wrong this exercise. What I have to do is the following

Let $(\Omega,\ \mathcal{H},\ \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $(Y_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ $\subset \mathbb{R}$. Prove or disprove that

$$ \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}(\{\sup_{j\geq k}|Y_{j}|>\epsilon\})=0 \ \forall\epsilon>0 \Rightarrow Y_{j}\rightarrow 0 \text{ a.s. } \text{for } j\rightarrow\infty$$

I hope to have understood that I should, in some way, use a convergence in probability result in order to imply a convergence in an almost sure sense. But it is not clear to me how I shuould do so!

Even small hints are welcomed, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hint: the sequence $\sup_{j\geq k}\vert Y_j\vert$ is by definition decreasing, therefore the pointwise limit exists, and coincides with the limit of any susbsequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**
Convergence in probability famously does not imply convergence a.s., but then again, the LHS isn't convergence in probability.

The sequence of events $\{\sup_{j\ge k}|Y_j| >\epsilon\}\downarrow_{k\to\infty} \{\limsup_{k\to \infty} |Y_k| \ge \epsilon\}$ so by the intersection property for finite measures, $$\lim_{k\to\infty}P(\sup_{j\ge k}|Y_j| >\epsilon) = P(\limsup_{k\to\infty} |Y_k| \ge\epsilon).$$

Can you finish from here?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "intersection property for finite measures"?

Comment: It's one of the main properties of measure and perhaps I've called it by the wrong name. It's just that for finite measures, if $E_n\downarrow E$ then $\mu(E_n)\to \mu(E)$. It's called 'continuity from above' on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Continuity_from_above